# Timeout on submitting huge data in a single html form field

Tags: php, html, gravityforms, litespeed

I am using gravityforms (wordpress) to create a form with lots of fields in it.

It was working fine until recently ... Not sure what has changed!

I extracted the forms section from the html and tested on my local server and it submits just fine, BUT in the server browser just gets stuck on `Sending request to X`(Firefox) and `Pending|Waiting for X`(chrome) part.

```
Server is LiteSpeed
PHP 7.2.20 
upload_max_filesize 64M
post_max_size 512M
max_input_vars 6000
memory_limit 2048M
```

I made a simple and standalone form for testing:
https://ererobot.com/botapi/test.php

what else should I increase to make this work???

UPDATE: I think the problem is with the LiteSpeed itself and not php!!

Comment: Did you find anything thing in web server logs (apache logs)?

Comment: @user3616545 Its a shared hosting and I don't have access to the logs

Comment: @Exlord Please view the output of **phpinfo()** to makes sure that configuration has correct values.